# Stripe page rendering issues

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

First of all, I created a payment intention with stripe to specify the payment method and amount

params :

```
{"payAmount":100,"payInvoiceMethod":"1","type":2,"notes":"ACH"}
```

result :

```
{"code":200,"data":{"clientSecret":"A1"}}
```

At this point I don't pay, I change the payment method, stripe generates a new clientSecret for me, I use the new clientSecret to generate the payment page, and the new generated payment page payment method is not correct

params :

```
{"payAmount":100,"payInvoiceMethod":"2","type":2,"notes":"CARD"}
```

result :

```
{"code":200,"data":{"clientSecret":"A2"}}
```

I closed and clocked in again, but the payment method on the payment page was correct

params :

```
{"payAmount":100,"payInvoiceMethod":"2","type":2,"notes":"CARD"}
```

result :

```
{"code":200,"data":{"clientSecret":"A2"}}
```

I don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you are using are not real parameters to Stripe's Create PaymentIntent [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create). This likely means that you are using a third-party tool to abstract away their API so it's not easy to explain how to do this.

The way you framed the question makes me think you are likely using Stripe's [PaymentElement](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element) which is their UI component to collect payment method details securely.

In that case, what you want is to call the `fetchUpdates()` [method](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/fetch_updates). Calling this will make Stripe.js retrieve the underlying PaymentIntent [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) to find the latest state and then reflect this in PaymentElement to have the right set of payment methods for example.

Comment: Yes, I've wrapped the stripe PaymentIntent create API in the background service, and stripe is going to give me a client_secret, and I'm going to give this back to the front end, The front end generates a payment page using Stripe's PaymentElement and client_secret, but the resulting payment page has the wrong payment method